# Disable scrolling while editting activity in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an activity that has ScrollView as it's main layout. Every time I make a change to something near the bottom, it will scroll back up to the top. Is there a way to disable this while I'm editing it?

[Snapshot of activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urz5t.png)

Here's a snapshot of the top of the activity. There are several more views below this. When I scroll down and make a change to any of the views below the ones shown in the picture, it will scroll back up to the top (to what's shown in the picture).

Here's a snippet of the XML. The rest of it is pretty much the exact same. Horizontal Linear layouts nested within a vertical linear layout, with TextViews and EditTexts in the Horizontal linear layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusedByDefault="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dip_information_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dip_information_title"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topo_shot_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="35"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/topo_shot_number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/topo_shot_number_entry_form"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="65"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/accessibility"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:text="@string/form_entry"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/cover_type_drop_down"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/cover_type_drop_down"
                android:nextFocusForward="@id/cover_type_drop_down"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that should not happen! please explain your question a little more! and also provide the working screen shot of the design and also snippet of your XML design hierarchy

Comment: I edited the question with more details

Comment: are you using getFocus property anywhere in xml? if not just set request focus false for scrollview

Comment: you are talking about editing in android studio, i.e. you are developing activity right?

Comment: @Rizwanatta No, I'm not using getFocus. I'm having trouble finding the request focus attribute, but I tried setting focusedByDefault=false but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @ShubhamVala Yeah, I'm developing an activity in android studio

Comment: how about adding a textWatcher class which listens to every ediText and when ever you try to type in something in it! it requests the focus automatically on itself

Comment: @Rizwanatta There's no problem when I actually run the app. My problem is when I'm editing the activity in android studio itself. I just want to be able to make changes to views near the bottom without it jumping back up to the top of the scrollview everytime I make an edit.

Comment: its not a natural behaviour in scrollView though! can you please share some of your xml code snippet! ! so that we could help you in your way of styling an xml

Comment: stop using xml focus props! and try! in the ediTexts